# Finding the non-intersecting rows in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find the non-intersecting rows in a large matrix. As an example:

```
A=[1 5 3; 3 4 5; 7 9 10;4 5 6;11 2 8; 3 5 10]
```

In this matrix, the non-intersecting rows are: `[1 5 3], [11 2 8]` and `[7 9 10]`. How can I program this in Matlab in a fast way?

Comment: What are non-intersecting rows?

Comment: @AndrasDeak From what I got, a row would not be considered in the final output, if any element from it is used in any row before that.

Comment: @Andras Deak: it is exactly as Divakar discussed. Thanks  Divakar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
M = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(unique(A),[3 2 1])),2))
[~,row_idx] = max(M,[],1)
out = A(sum(M,2).' == histc(row_idx,1:size(A,1)),:)
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
A =
     1     5     3
     3     4     5
     7     9    10
     4     5     6
    11     2     8
     3     5    10
M =
     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
row_idx =
     1     5     1     2     1     4     3     5     3     3     5
out =
     1     5     3
     7     9    10
    11     2     8
```

Comment: I was looking at `bsxfun`, but got beaten by the `intersect` function I tried to use. Good work

Comment: "If I may `bsxfun`": who may if not you?;)

Comment: @asd2014 To allow for one value intersection, you can do : `out = A(sum(M,2).' - histc(row_idx,1:size(A,1)) <= 1,:)`.

Comment: @Divakar this solution is perfect. However, my matrices are of sym type. therefore, bsxfun does not deal with sym variables.

Comment: @asd2014 Yes, that would be a problem then. Symbolic variables are a whole new ball game.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for rows that adding them to union of previous rows increases the number of elements in the union by the number of columns (i.e. all elements in that row are new):

```
B = []; 
C = zeros(1,size(A,1)); 
for k=1:size(A,1), 
    B1 = union(B, A(k,:)); 
    C(k) = numel(B1)-numel(B); 
    B=B1; 
end
result = A(C==size(A,2),:);
```